# Starting blank in java editor template

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, editor

I wrote myself a template for TODOs in Java:

```
 TODO ${date} ${user}:
```

If I write '//me' and use autocompletion I get '//TODO 19.10.2015 username: '.
If I use format it changes to '// TODO 19.10.2015 username: '. (Note the blank before the TODO!).

I want a blank before my TODO. How can I achieve this?

Comment: by the way, I prefer to add a template with the name "todo" with the template "// TODO ${date} ${user}: ", so I don't need to to type "//" and have no problem with the space

Comment: @SergejWerfel Thank you. That's what I acutally did ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can type `// me` instead of `//me`.

Other than that, it seems to be a [bug of Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=218999):

> Leading whitespace is trimmed from a Java Editor Templates before insertion

As a workaround, you can enter a non-breaking space (at least in Eclipse 4.5.0 on Windows, using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0160</kbd> on Numpad).

Comment: I thought of this solution as well, but firstly I am used to type '//me' and secondly I would have to hit one more button. Maybe there is something like a 'devaluator'.

Comment: Works as well in JBoss Developer Studio 8.0.0.GA.

Comment: I found a problem while working with this workaround: the formatter still intends the TODO. I think this is because the formatter doesnt recognize that the non-breaking space is a space :-(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a workaround or by design.

Insert a non-resolvable variable to prevent the trimming to happen, e.g.:

```
${} TODO ${date} ${user}:
```

Comment: Unfortunately (and curiously) the curser get's positioned just behind the backslashes. In order to write a comment for the TODO, this is a bad behavior.

Comment: Oh well. @Thomas answer seems more useful than. I have upvoted it myself